# Generating CSV document via link

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, csv, download, actionmethod

I have a link on a page and I'd like a "open or save csv file" dialog to appear when the user clicks on the link.  The link points to an action method in which I generate a string representing valid CSV output.  The only thing I don't know how to do is output a file that the user can open or save.  I think I might have to do something about changing the http headers or something like that but I'm not too sure.

Please help.  It'll make the difference between getting home at a reasonable time on a Friday evening or not. ;-).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Return as `FileContentResult` and put MIME type as "text/csv".

```
public FileContentResult Download()
{
    string csvContent = "field1,field2,field3";
    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csvContent);
    string filename = "Simple.csv";
    string mime = "text/csv";
    return File(data, mime, filename);
}
```

In the view page, simply creat a link to prompt for download.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download File", "Download")
```